# photorec alternative for scanning ram dumps?

Tags: data-recovery

I want to scan some RAM dumps for files.  I was hoping I could use PhotoRec, but it prompts me to select a hard drive, and not scan from a file.

Is there a way to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: @Takkat, I just realized you can do that [by looking at the man page]. Guess I should have tried that first. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

:E  wow, I feel dumb, all you have to do is specify the file `photorec dump.img`

Comment: jinx to my comment above ;)